Project/Georeference png using gdal-transform
I am struggling to get the projection of a png correct.
I am downloading this image:
https://gdi.berlin.de/services/wms/truedop_2023?SERVICE=wms&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&service=wms&layers=truedop_2023&styles=truedop_2023&crs=EPSG%3A25833&width=2048&height=2048&format=image%2Fpng&bbox=392680.9553887303%2C5816991.938520388%2C393134.43388141005%2C5817424.944091731&transparent=true
The result is a png which is not georeferenced, so I thought I can do the referencing with gdal translate using this information:
EPSG:25833 (from the wms link)
and this as the bbox:
{
  sw: [ 392680.9553887303, 5816991.938520388 ],
  ne: [ 393134.43388141005, 5817424.944091731 ],
  se: [ 393124.777973969, 5816982.242881533 ],
  nw: [ 392690.64227662125, 5817434.639570712 ]
}

(also the source for the wms link)
I do the translation like this (in node, but it's the same result if I do it directly in bash)
await gdal.translateAsync(georefImagePath, ds, [
// ulx uly lrx lry
// coordinates from wms download
'-of',
'GTiff',
'-a_srs',
wmsCrs,
'-a_ullr',
NwX.toString(),
NwY.toString(),
SeX.toString(),
SeY.toString(),
])
or directly in bash:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr 392690.64227662125 5817434.639570712 393124.777973969 5816982.242881533 -a_srs EPSG:25833 'tmp_16_35211_21500.png' 'tmp_16_35211_21500_georefferenced.tiff'

The output file is a tiff. BUT: it is slightly off if I open it in qgis for example. What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing?

I think I have found one Problem:
the WFS server uses Boundingboxes with SE / NW corners, gdal uses NE / SW corners. If I overlay image and BBoxes the lower left corner (SE looks like this:

Is there any way to also use SE / NW corners for gdaltranslate?

why not just open the WMS in QGis and let it do the heavy lifting? or if you need a Georeferenced image use GDALTranslate to do it directly from the WMS or use a WCS endpoint that is designed for this

Hi there, i am using qgis for debugging. in the end i need this in a nodejs application. what is a WCS endpoint?

WCS is a standard that returns actual raster data

Use the same coordinates that appear in the GetMap bbox parameters for georeferencing the image.
bbox=
392680.9553887303
5816991.938520388
393134.43388141005
5817424.944091731

I is not clear to me how did you get some of these values:
  sw: [ 392680.9553887303, 5816991.938520388 ],
  ne: [ 393134.43388141005, 5817424.944091731 ],
  se: [ 393124.777973969, 5816982.242881533 ],
  nw: [ 392690.64227662125, 5817434.639570712 ]

-a_ullr 392690.64227662125 5817434.639570712 393124.777973969 5816982.242881533 

With the bbox coordinates:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr 392680.9553887303 5817424.944091731 393134.43388141005 5816991.938520388 -a_srs EPSG:25833 'tmp_16_35211_21500.png' 'tmp_16_35211_21500_correctly_georeferenced.tiff'

the result looks like this:

Note: That WMS service is using a self-signed certificate and I could not add it into QGIS despite I tried to make it to ignore the certificate error.

Hi, if i run the command exactly like you supposed to do, i get the same slightly wrong image from my first post. this is how i ran the command: gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr 392690.64227662125 5817434.639570712 393124.777973969 5816982.242881533 -a_srs EPSG:25833 '1234.png' '4321.tiff'
the server is the official berlin state server. i guess its not a self signed cert (issuer: Telekom Security ServerID OV Class 2 CA)

i think the root of the problem is the following: i make a wms query with upperleft and lower right point in a non-meter projection system. as a return i get a rectangular image. to use gdal-transform, i need the lowerleft and upperright corner. but i dont have that information. the return of the wms is always perfectly straight, but projected it is not (slightly)

The WMS GetMap is using BoundingBox that is an axis oriented rectangle (MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY).  Because it is oriented, all four corners of the rectangle are known. Lowerleft is minx,miny, upperleft is minx,maxy, upperright is maxx,maxy, and lowerright is maxx,miny (when the coordinate system is north-up and y grows from the Equator).
You do not run exactly my command, you have changed the coordinates.
